# Is it normal that after clicking a Rails link_to method all the options appear in the URL bar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in one of my views:

```
  <%= link_to "Vote up",   :url => {:controller => :votes, :action => :vote_up, :id => i.id},
                           :update => "total_value_#{i.id}",
                           :remote => true %>
  <%= link_to "Vote down", :url => {:controller => :votes, :action => :vote_down, :id => i.id},
                           :update => "total_value_#{i.id}", 
                           :remote => true %>
```

When I click say, *Vote up*, I get something like this in the URL:

> http://localhost:3000/?remote=true&update=total_value_29&url%5Baction%5D=vote_up&url%5Bcontroller%5D=votes&url%5Bid%5D=29

The action is in a controller called **votes_controller.rb:**

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def vote_up
    check = Votes.find(:first,
                       :conditions => ["user_id = ? AND post_id = ?", session[:user_id], params[:id]])

    post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if check.nil?
      vote = Votes.new
      vote.post_id = params[:id]
      vote.user_id = session[:user_id]
      vote.value = true
      vote.save
      post.total_value += 1
      post.save
      render :text => post.total_value
    elsif check.value == false
      check.value = true
      check.save
      post.total_value += 2
      post.save
      render :text => post.total_value
    else
      render :text => "You have already voted up for this post."
    end
  end

  def vote_down
    check = Vote.find(:first,
                      :conditions => ["user_id = ? AND post_id = ?", session[:user_id], params[:id]])

    post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if check.nil?
      vote = Vote.new
      vote.post_id = params[:id]
      vote.user_id = session[:user_id]
      vote.value = true
      vote.save
      post.total_value -= 1
      post.save
      render :text => post.total_value
    elsif check.value == true
      check.value = false
      check.save
      post.total_value -= 2
      post.save
      render :text => post.total_value
    else
      render :text => "You have already voted down for this post."
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if this is normal or I have a syntax error somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options to `link_to` just don't look like that, rails thinks that all the options you are giving it are routing options

```
link_to 'link text', {:controller => ..., :action => ...}, {:remote => true, ...}
```

Is more like it. Anything that isn't supposed to be used to build the URL should be in the second hash (there are lots of examples in the [api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to))