# How to fix this Rails 3 link_to method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following `link_to` methods:

```
<%= link_to "Vote up",   :url => {:controller => :votes, :action => :vote_up, :id => i.id},
                         :update => "total_value_#{i.id}",
                         :remote => true %>
<%= link_to "Vote down", :url => {:controller => :votes, :action => :vote_down, :id => i.id},
                         :update => "total_value_#{i.id}", 
                         :remote => true %>
```

I think there are some parts where I need `{}` or `()`. But I'm not sure where.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I get no syntax errors just this strange URL:

> http://localhost:3000/?remote=true&update=total_value_29&url%5Baction%5D=vote_up&url%5Bcontroller%5D=votes&url%5Bid%5D=29

The link should trigger the action in the controller.

Comment: How about telling us your syntax errors?

Comment: @pduersteler Sorry I updated my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it normal that after clicking a Rails link_to method all the options appear in the URL bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088632/is-it-normal-that-after-clicking-a-rails-link-to-method-all-the-options-appear-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read carefully here about usage of link_to method:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to